# Split multiple lines by regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to split multiple lines of a segment from an ttl document, here's the relevant code.

```
entry_obj = str(Entry(*re.findall(r'([;\s]+[^\s+|\s+$])', ''.join(buf))))
            yield process_entry_obj(entry_obj)
```

The code returns the error and as it is not able to split the string, the number of matching arguments are different every time and code doesn't run.

Below is my file format:

```
 File input

 ##  http://www.example.com/abc#AAA
                pms:ecCreatedBy rms:type ;
                rmfs:lag "Ersteller"@newyork ,
                "AAA"@wdc .
```

There are multiple entries like above in the file.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what your *string* input looks like and what you expect as output.The regex you tried is a total disaster, it is not helpful to deduce what you are up to, and looks like a splitting regex, but you are using `re.findall`.

Comment: Yes Thanks Wiktor. I am trying to read the file and and and split the content of the file on the basis of  semicolon, whitespace and line which ends with (Full stop " . ").

Comment: So, what is the expected output for the ttl format string you posted?

Comment: Michał, don't change the [original data](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0ed4549b-a974-4cef-b3d2-02e266985695/view-source) posted by OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Lets have a chat so i can explain what exactly i am trying to achieve in this solution.

Comment: No, please edit the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Have updated the question

Comment: So, you do not need to split anything, you want to modify the existing file, right? I understand you just want to add something to URLs. What is the expected result? Add to the question.

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew I do not need to split, if i am able to edit the content of file and save it either in the same file or in different file with same name.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/AwN8AP/1 will be enough, or do you really need to swap the `rmfs:label` values to make the `@en` one the first?

Comment: Yes i need to swap those values at-sign_en with @ce if at-sign-en values are not at the first place in rmfs : label

Comment: See https://ideone.com/8Mas4z

Comment: Excellent Wiktor , Hats off to the skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

s = "" # File contents
with open(filepath, 'r') as fr:
    s =fr.read()
s = re.sub(r'(?m)(rmfs:label\s*)("[^"]*"@(?!en)\w*)(\s*,\s*)("[^"]*"@en) \.$', r'\1\4\3\2 .', s)
s = re.sub(r'(?m)^(\s*###\s*http.*/v\d+#)\w*((?:\n(?!\n).*)*rmfs:label\s*")([^"]*)("@en)', r'\1\3\2\3\4', s)
# Wrtie to file:
with open(filepath, 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8Mas4z).

Here are the [Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/AwN8AP/2) and [Regex 2 demos](https://regex101.com/r/AwN8AP/1).

**Regex 1 details**

- `(?m)` - multiline mode, `$` will match end of a line
- `(rmfs:label\s*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `rmfs:label` and then 0+ whitespaces
- `("[^"]*"@(?!en)\w*)` - Group 2 (`\2`): `"`, 0+ non-`"` chars, `"@`, a lookahead check ensuring no `en` immediately to the right of the current position, and then 0+ word chars
- `(\s*,\s*)` - Group 3 (`\3`): a `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `("[^"]*"@en)` - Group 4 (`\4`): `"`, 0+ chars other than `"`, `"` and `@en`
- `.$` - space, `.`, end of line.

**Regex 2 details**

- `(?m)` - multiline mnode, `^` matche line start
- `^` - start of  a line
- `(\s*###\s*http.*/v\d+#)` - Group 1: 0+ whitespaces, `###`, 0+ whitespaces, `http`, any 0+ chars, `/v`, 1+ digits and `#`
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `((?:\n(?!\n).*)*rmfs:label\s*")`  - Group 2: any amount of lines before a double line break (`(?:\n(?!\n).*)*`) and then `rmfs:label`, 0+ whitespaces and `"`
- `([^"]*)`  - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `("@en)` - Group 4: `"@en` siubstring.

Comment: The solution doesn't work when we consolidate all the operations that is 1)read the file 2)change the content of it 3)write to the file , as suggested by you. However the regex works when provide raw data from the program itself like we have provided earlier by using s="..". but it doesn't work with file I/O operations. I am trying other options such as compiling the regex and then put for file I/O but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Raj Replace `\n` with `\r?\n` if you have CLRF endings

Comment: I am trying to remove white space also from the string which we have to replace with URl as URL can't have whitespace.To do this i tried 1) split() method to remove both leading and trailing white space and 2)By adding  re.sub("(?m)^\s+", "", text) regex. Not sure why it is not removing the white space.  Thank you very much for your input :)

Comment: @Raj Removing whitespace is done with `re.sub(r'\s+', '', text)`. To remove horizontal whitespace, use `[^\S\r\n]+` instead of `\s+`. If you need more concrete, specific help, please share 1) your current relevant code, 2) string input, 3) expected output.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Wiktor :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you need `\s*;\s*`

Explanation:

`\s*` - match whitespace character zero or more times

`;` - match `;` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/laEqIF/1)

Comment: @Raj If answer helped you you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am getting error while it is trying to find or split the string, once it is getting  colon in the string and because of it it is not able to split the string